# How can I call a coroutine from another coroutine in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have a long coroutine and I would like to divide it into smaller coroutines. Just like with regular functions, to make the code more clear. It should behave just like there was only one big coroutine with all the smaller ones happening consecutively.

I'm using `#include <experimental/coroutine>`.

I've been trying something like this:

```
resumable part1_coroutine()
{
    cout << "1" << endl;
    co_await suspend_always();
}

resumable part2_coroutine()
{
    cout << "2" << endl;
    co_await suspend_always();
}

resumable main_coroutine()
{
    cout << "main" << endl;
    part1_coroutine();
    part2_coroutine();
    co_await suspend_always();
}
```

But what seems to happen is that the `part1_coroutine()` and `part2_coroutine()` won't be executed at all.

Comment: It's not clear what `suspend_always` and `resumable` are meant to achieve.

Comment: @NicolBolas `suspend_always` is `std::experimental::suspend_always`. And `resumable` is from here: https://blog.panicsoftware.com/your-first-coroutine/

Comment: That doesn't explain what you're trying to *achieve* by using them. Why do these functions `co_await suspend_always()` at the end? Why do they return `resumable` and use the accompanying promise type? Why do you discard the `resumable` that the `part1` and `part2` functions return? You say that you want these functions to behave like one coroutine, but I don't see anything here that behaves like a coroutine.

Comment: I have a function that takes eg. a minute to complete (`main_coroutine()`). I don't want it to block the execution of the rest of the program. It consists of many smaller pieces that take, say, 1 second each (`part1_coroutine`). It's ok if those block the execution. I could make a thread. But I'd rather use a coroutine because it would make communicating with the main program easier. I've previously used coroutines with Unity and C# and this was something that I did on a regular basis. Maybe I simplified my example too much, but I didn't want it to look too complicated.

Comment: It would really help if you just showed us what the "long coroutine" version of the code you're trying to write is. Like, take the above code, and write the long form version of it.

Answer (score 3):

This is what `co_await foo()` *does*—give another coroutine `foo` a chance to make progress, suspending the *current* coroutine as necessary to wait on it to finish.  If you just call a coroutine but don’t await it, you throw away the handle for that call to it, abandoning the call.

Comment: I see. But I still don't understand it, because If I try to do `co_await part1_coroutine();` I get the error "no callable 'await_resume' function found for type 'resumable'". Which is understandable because as far as I've understood, after `co_await` there should be an Awaiter object, and not a coroutine call or whatever is the correct term for it. I don't think an Awaiter is the same thing, because the requirement for an Awaiter is that it has the functions `await_ready`, `await_suspend` and `await_resume`, and I don't quite understand what those have to do with the coroutine call itself.

Comment: @kynnysmatto: That seems to be a limitation of the example you’re following: it doesn’t go far enough to support nested coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, coroutines are not awaitables. As described in the standard, a coroutine can suspend only by interacting with awaitables (co_awaiting them). In order to call a coroutine from another coroutine, it has to be made into an awaitable. So you have to implement awaitable API on the object returned by the coroutine. So there is quite some amount of plumbing to build to make this work.